# Django Rest Framework - TypeError: reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a number of tests written for a django application, and all tests must pass in order for automated deployment to take place.

Unexpectedly, a number of tests began failing, none of which had been touched with the latest commit. The error comes from a serializer that uses django rest frameworks 'reverse' function.

```
# serializers.py

from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, SerializerMethodField
from my_app.models import ConfigVersion

class ConfigVersionMetadataSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ConfigVersion
        fields = ('id', 'config', 'config_name',
                  'hyperlink', 'version')

    hyperlink = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_hyperlink(self, obj):
        return reverse(
            'versions-list',
            kwargs={
                'configurations_pk': obj.config.id,
                'version_pk': obj.id
            },
            request=self.context['request']
            )
```

All tests that call this serializer now fail with error `TypeError: reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'`

Django rest frameworks documentation states that 'request' is an included and recommended argument https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/.

After reviewing the documentation, I have searched for dependency version changes in the build logs to see if there were code changes, but the only dependency update is presumably unrelated (pytz). I'm pretty confused by the source of this issue, since tests were working properly a couple days ago and there don't appear to be any changes to the tests, serializers, views, or required libraries.

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback

Answer (score 0):

try use reverse_lazy instead.

```
    return reverse_lazy(
        'versions-list',
        kwargs={
            'configurations_pk': obj.config.id,
            'version_pk': obj.id
        },
        request=self.context['request']
        )
```